# Approximating dot product between two real-valued vectors in Hamming space

Tags: python, vector, linear-algebra, dot-product

currently I am reading a paper about quantization in graph neural networks (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.15823.pdf). On page two they talk about how you can approximate the dot product of two real-valued vectors a and b

[image: approximation of real-valued vectors]

Now I tried to implement this in Python but I get something that is nowhere near a good approximation when there are negative numbers:

```
dataset = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (500, 300))
dataset /= np.linalg.norm(dataset, axis=1, keepdims=True)

def sign(vector):
    return 2* (vector > 0).astype(int) - 1

def rescaling(vector):
    return (1 / vector.size) * np.sum(np.abs(vector))

def binary_product(vector_x, vector_y):
    return (vector_x == vector_y).sum()


def calculate_approx(a, b):
    alpha = rescaling(a)
    beta = rescaling(b)

    sign_a = sign(a)
    sign_b = sign(b)

    return binary_product(sign_a, sign_b) * alpha * beta

print(calculate_approx(dataset[0], dataset[1]))
print(dataset[0] @ dataset[1])
```

When I change the dataset to have only values higher than 0 I do get a good approximation.

Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You see that the derivation assumes `allclose(|x|, 1)`

[image]

With the rescaling `mean(|x|)` parameter you can have `allclose(|x|, mean(|x|))`,
the dot product could be rewritten as `sum(sign(x) * sign(y) * |x| * |y|)`, what you are calculating is `sum(sign(x) * sign(y)) mean(|x|) * mean(|y|)`, if both `|x|` and `|y|` are close to their respective averages then you get a good approximation.